# Why doesn't `npm run bundle -- -p` (webpack -p) compile the asset for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, service, daemon

I forked this rails project (https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap) and try to set it up following its [installation guide](https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap/wiki/Installation)

When following the installation guide:

1) Before the step: `npm run bundle`, the website doesn't show its image and layout properly

2) After the step `npm run bundle`, the website show its image and layout properly

3) Under the hood, `npm run bundle` will start webpack. I close the webpack by pressing CTRL + C after `npm run bundle`, and the website is still showing image and layout properly.

4) I run `npm run bundle -- -p` which should be equal to `webpack -p`, and the website does not display the images and layout properly anymore.

Why is `npm run bundle -- -p` (which is `webpack -p`) not compiling the asset properly? I thought it is the daemon version of `npm run bundle` (which is `webpack`) and daemon means running in background (I thought daemon is the same as service?)?

Please correct me if I understand the concept incorrectly or use the term incorrectly anywhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question:

> 1) Before the step: `npm run bundle`, the website doesn't show its image
>   and layout properly

The asset (image and css stylesheet's layout) is not compiled yet, so Rails can't use it and hence the layout will not be correct and the image will not show.

You can compile the asset for development environment using `npm run bundle` in this project.

> 2) After the step `npm run bundle`, the website shows its image and
>   layout properly

See above.

> 3) Under the hood, `npm run bundle` will start webpack. I close the
>   webpack by pressing CTRL + C after `npm run bundle`, and the website
>   is still showing image and layout properly.

I thought webpack (`npm run bundle`) acts like a server, serving the rails server asset they need, but actually this is not true.

webpack only compiles the asset for rails to use. The reason that webpack keep running after you ran `npm run bundle` is because it is constantly detecting change to the source of those asset file, so that any change to the source of those asset file will be reflected immediately when you issue a browser refresh on the website.

> 4) I run `npm run bundle -- -p` which should be equal to `webpack -p`,
>   and the website does not display the images and layout properly
>   anymore.
>   Why is npm run bundle -- -p (which is webpack -p) not compiling the
>   asset properly?

`npm run bundle -- -p` indeed equals to `webpack -p` in this case.

To understand why the website does not display the images and layout properly anymore, let's see something first. When I run `npm run bundle -- p` the below happen:

```
modified:   config/initializers/fingerprint.rb

deleted:    public/javascripts/application.js
deleted:    public/javascripts/vendor.js
deleted:    public/stylesheets/application.css

added:      public/javascripts/application-2f49ec37563f77c91204.js
added:      public/javascripts/vendor-2f49ec37563f77c91204.js
added:      public/stylesheets/application-2f49ec37563f77c91204.css
```

`npm run bundle -- -p` will compile the asset for production environment, and will add fingerprint (in this case it's `-2f49ec37563f77c91204`) to its output.

Digging into the code, we can see that `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` has the following code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag fingerprinted_asset('application') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag fingerprinted_asset('vendor') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag fingerprinted_asset('application') %>
```

Looking at the `fingerprinted_asset()` method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`, we can see that:

```
  def fingerprinted_asset(name)
    Rails.env.production? ? "#{name}-#{ASSET_FINGERPRINT}" : name
  end
```

We can see that in production we will use file with fingerprint in their name and in non production environment we will use file without fingerprint in their name.

In this case, I was running `rails server` in development environemtn, so my application try to look for files without fingerprint in their name. That means these:

```
public/javascripts/application.js
public/javascripts/vendor.js
public/stylesheets/application.css
```

But I use `npm run bundle -- -p`, which deletes the above file and produces the fingerprinted version of them, so rails can't find it and hence display no image and display incorrect layout to me.

> I thought it is the daemon version of `npm run bundle` (which is
>   webpack) and daemon means running in background (I thought daemon is
>   the same as service?)?

It is not the daemon version of `npm run bundle`. I thought it is the daemon version of `npm run bundle` because their wiki used to say so which is wrong, see https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap/issues/1782.